# ag grid Passing KeyPress/Enter event to apply filter

Tags: filter, apply, ag-grid

I want to use the same logic when I press the **APPLY** button but with the **ENTER key**.

How do I do that?

```
filterParams: {
                        closeOnApply:true,
                        buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
                        values: parentCampaignAndNodes.PaymentGroups
                    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you might have found out by now, you can remove the Apply button (by setting `filterParams: { buttons: [] }` in your column definitions) and then values are submitted onchange.

The solution you ask for is indeed still not available through the AgGrid API. I do have a workaround, but beware it uses direct DOM bindings which is not recommended when working with React.

```
const applyFilterOnEnter: AgGridReactProps['onFilterOpened'] = ev => {
  const inputElem = ev.eGui.querySelector('.ag-filter-body .ag-input-field');
  const applyButtonElem = ev.eGui.querySelector('.ag-filter-apply-panel button[ref=applyFilterButton]');
  if (inputElem && applyButtonElem) {
    inputElem.addEventListener('keydown', keyEv => {
      if ((keyEv as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Enter') {
        (applyButtonElem as HTMLButtonElement).click();
      }
    });
  }
};

return <AgGridReact
  onFilterOpened={applyFilterOnEnter}
/>
```